# JMeter - 5.4.1 gives StackOverFlowError when running in GUI and non-GUI mode, Xmx 12G, Xms 8G

Tags: java, jmeter, stack-overflow

I have a JMeter script taken from other teams, and when I try to run it, it gives `StackOverFlowError`. When I select different node in the test, the stack traces are different, but they are similar AWT(GUI) thread errors.

I have this test:

[image]

You see that I have many disabled tests, only one is not greyed out(enabled).

And when I click Run in GUI mode, I got:

```java
2022-01-10 12:56:14,893 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:440) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:2584) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getProperty(AbstractTestElement.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.isEnabled(AbstractTestElement.java:623) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.isEnabled(JMeterTreeNode.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
...
```

The java version is Oracle 8u202, Jmeter version 5.4.1.

Things I tried:

- run in non-GUI mode (`-t xxx.jmx -n`), almost same error:

```java
2022-01-10 13:06:03,781 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:2584) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getProperty(AbstractTestElement.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.isEnabled(AbstractTestElement.java:623) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.isEnabled(JMeterTreeNode.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1206) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.pConvertSubTree(JMeter.java:1212) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
...
```

- adjust JVM Heap memory to Xms=8G, Xmx=12G, not working
- remove the disabled tests completely, save it, and try GUI and non-GUI run, not working

Anyone seeing similar situations? Thanks.

EDIT: it turns out the content of this file has changed quite a bit and got messed up in the version control system. Finally got a clean version and tests starts to work; now this is not an issue anymore, we can close the question.

Comment: It looks like some sort of recursive call that isn't terminating. So more memory doesn't really help. It seems broken. What about the code that is causing the issue?

Comment: You mean the test plan itself? Or what code.

Comment: It has a java tag, so I thought there was some java code involved.  It seems the "answer" provided is asking for the test plan though. In general, you should provide enough information for somebody to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK nevermind, at last the file was corrupted so Jmeter cannot parse it. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should address this question to the "other teams", not to us, we can help only if we see the full test plan (or at lest schematic view)

[image]

and full [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

With regards to your problem, double check your test plan and ensure that:

1. There are no nested inclusions (module controller which includes test fragment pointing to itself via another module controller)
2. All Test fragments are disabled or are put under disabled [Logic Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) or put under disabled thread group

More information:

- [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)
- [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)

Comment: Oh, you reported this issue. Good try. At least we got some official answer. Thanks.